# Install Dlib on device without gpu

Tags: cpu, face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to run a face recognition program using dlib and facetorch, installing them on a python -m venv. I understand that it is necessary to install the dlib package for cpu only, without cuda.
In another post it was said to install the following line: pip --no-cache-dir install -v --install-option="--no" --install-option="DLIB_USE_CUDA" dlib (answer 3 - [Force Dlib python to install with CPU support only; on a GPU machine with Cuda and everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096802/force-dlib-python-to-install-with-cpu-support-only-on-a-gpu-machine-with-cuda-a))

My problem now is that I am receiving the following message:

```
Usage:
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\venv_py38\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...       
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\venv_py38\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...        
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\venv_py38\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\venv_py38\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\venv_py38\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --install-option
```

Any suggestions on how to get it to work?

The original issue stemmed from the following error trying to run the program after installing the regular dlib package:

```
File "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\venv_py38\lib\site-packages\face_recognition\api.py", line 26, in <module>
cnn_face_detector = dlib.cnn_face_detection_model_v1(cnn_face_detection_model)
RuntimeError: Error while calling cudaGetDevice(&the_device_id) in file C:\Users\Zvi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zmzuw640\dlib_fd3bb48614424c50b9905f6916aefb5b\dlib\cuda\gpu_data.cpp:204. code: 35, reason: CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version
```

Note: I updated the cuda version to the latest of cuda 12.1

I tried installing dlib and face_recognition packages for running a face recognition program.

I expected to launch the program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work around:

The error in pip --install-option, it has been depreciated.

> sudo pip install -v --config-settings ="--no" --config-settings ="DLIB_USE_CUDA" dlib

Please use this command instead of the old one, its working for me atm.

The thing is this command setting the installation configs to don't use CUDA, which as always takes a lot of time, i  was searching for a distribution that depends on CPU by default, minimum requirements, a light CPU version!